# Debugging Google Analytics message errors

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I'm using the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) to push data to Google Analytics.

The [protocol reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference#response-codes) says that the endpoint (`http://www.google-analytics.com/collect`) always returns 200 OK, even if your message was malformed and/or ignored.

If my message is ignored, how do I know what I did wrong? Trial and error?

For example, the parameter reference says that [Application Name ("an=Name") is an optional parameter for web properties](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#an). However, if I add this my requests, Google starts ignoring them completely. Why? More importantly, how can I *find out* why on my own? Is there a log the [Google Analytics portal](https://www.google.com/analytics/web) somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You can debug Measurement Protocol hits with the [Measurement Protocol Hit Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/).

This tool works by sending hits to the [Measurement Protocol Validation Server](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits) behind the scenes to validate the hits and report error messages. The document linked here goes into more detail on how to send hits to this service manually if you wanted.

Comment: The hit builder says "Hit is valid!".  Yet Google Analytics ignores it. Here's the actual message (slightly sanitized): `v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-1&cid=561d0e8f-d99e-4542-8208-bad5a4c03f10&dh=hostname.com&an=testapp&t=pageview&dp=%2ftestpage&dt=testpage`. If I remove `&an=testapp`, GA processes it. If I leave it in, it doesn't. Supposedly this is a perfectly valid [optional parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#an).

Comment: Are you sending these hits to an app view or a web view?

Comment: Web view. The docs say that Application Name is required for an app view but [optional for a web view](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#an). My particular web app is Silverlight app and I find the Application Name parameter useful, but I can work around not using it. However, the larger question is how one gets insight to why Google Analytics is ignoring a message.

Comment: To answer your larger question, if GA is ignoring a hit that the Measurement Protocol Validation Server is saying is valid, that's a bug (and I'm looking into it). The MPVS is how you're supposed to be able to find these things out on your own. That's the whole point of the tool.

Comment: Did you find out if there is a problem, either in GA itself or the documentation?